# #states does not hide #suffix in a form

Tags: 7, javascript

I am new to Drupal, so please be fair with me :)

I am trying to create a custom form using FAPI. The code is as follows :

```
$form['format_document'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
    'yes' => t('Yes'),
    'no' => t('No')
  ),
  '#title' => t('Should we format your document?:'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 'no',

  '#suffix' => 'markup for the help image',

  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="select_service"]' => array(
        array('value' => '1'),
        array('value' => '2'),
        array('value' => '3'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The `#states` work fine on the form element visibility; however the `#suffix` part is always visible. I can create a new form element with the same #states, but I have to do this on large number of elements. Is there something I am missing in the `#states`?

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly how it is designed to work. `#suffix` is rendered outside element's template, so `#states` have no way to know about it. Depending on what you need this 'Some custom HTML' for, solutions may be different.

Comment: @Mołot Thank you for the prompt response. The custom HTML is a help image for the element.

Comment: As @Mołot said, states refer _only_ to the element, and the suffix isn't part of the element..you'll need to write custom javascript to accomplish this.

Comment: cool @Clive .. !!! thnx.. :)

Comment: @Clive There is a way to have image inside wrapper, and it's compatible with states. So custom JS is just one of the options, not something OP *needs* to do. PHP solution is not worth implementing for one field, I freely admit, but for dozens or hundreds? I did it, and I found it worth doing in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You could put your form element with the suffix into a container forms element. The container can also have states:

```
$form['format_document_container'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="select_service"]' => array(
        array('value' => '1'),
        array('value' => '2'),
        array('value' => '3'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

$form['format_document_container']['format_document'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
    'yes' => t('Yes'),
    'no' => t('No')
  ),
  '#title' => t('Should we format your document?:'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 'no',

  '#suffix' => 'markup for the help image',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. Problem is that `#suffix` is rendered outside element's template, so #states have no way to know about it.

My solution was to put image inside element. First, I registered it's theme function in my module:

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'preview_upload' => array(
      'render element' => 'element',
      'file' => 'mymodule.module',
    ),
  );
}
```

And then I defined this function as follows:

```
function theme_preview_upload($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  $attributes = array();
  if (isset($element['#id'])) {
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
  }
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $attributes['class'] = (array) $element['#attributes']['class'];
  }
  $attributes['class'][] = 'form-managed-file';

  // This wrapper is required to apply JS behaviors and CSS styling.
  $output = '';
  $output .= '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';
  if (isset($element['#file']->uri)) {
    $output .= '<img src="' . image_style_url('thumbnail', $element['#file']->uri) . '" class="preview" />';
  }
  $output .= drupal_render_children($element);
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Now wherever I add `'#theme' => 'preview_upload'` to my `'#type' => 'managed_file'` elements, it provides me with preview image *inside* element's wrapper.

## **How** I did it, exactly?

I searched [api.drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/), found the original theme function for the element I wanted co change ([`theme_file_managed_file`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_managed_file/7)), copied it to new name and edited last lines, the `$output .=` block. Just do the same.

Remember that you can add arbitrary attributes to your form element. Nothing against setting:

```
'#theme' => 'with_help_image',
'#help_image' => 'http://example.com/sites/default/files/image.png',
```

and then using `$element['#help_image']` in a way similar I was using `$element['#file']`, if your form element does not have this image "naturally".

---

Of course you may also forget `#states` and create custom JS code, that will be aware of your `#suffix`. Choice is ultimately yours, I would prefer theme change and built-in states, but it's just my own "I feel it's simpler in the long run" opinion, not a hard measurable fact.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I found a easier way to do this actually using `#field_suffix`. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Abhay #field_suffix is less universal. It is supposed to work only for checkbox, machine_name, password, password_confirm, radio, select, textarea and textfield. You are using radios, not radio, so it **shouldn't**, by the docs, to be possible to use #field_suffix.

Answer (score 1):

On searching through the documentation of Form API, I found that there is a shorter way of doing this.

I have used [`#field_suffix`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#field_suffix) instead of '#suffix' and it works.. !!

The suffix that is being added this way actually becomes a part of the main div wrapping the element.

Comment: Good answer. Not universal one, as it only applies to very limited set of field types, but if it works, all right. Surprisingly, **'radios' are not on the list** of types that accept #field_suffix, so **it shouldn't work** in your case.